# How to run all possible combinations in multiple linear regression model in R

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, statistics, regression

I have a data set of 7 variables and I want to run all possible combinations. What I exactly want is to run is different equations which choose different variables, for instance:

```
Y = b_0 + b_1*X_1 + b_2*X_2
Y = b_0 + b_1*X_1 + b_2*X_3
Y = b_0 + b_1*X_1 + b_2*X_2 + b_3*X_3
Y = b_0 + b_1*X_1 + b_2*X_2 + b_3*X_3 + b_2*X_4
Y = b_0 + b_1*X_1 + b_2*X_2 + b_2*X_4 
Y = b_0 + b_1*X_1 + b_2*X_4
```

All possible combination in this order. How should I setup my loop function?

Comment: Thanks! I am very much new to stack overflow.

Comment: Search on all subsets regression. Fancy data dredging.

Comment: Not recommended. But if you really want to do so, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705153/generate-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-elements-of-vector).

Comment: You can check this out too but there is probably a better way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58946505/10142537

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate example data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  Y = rnorm(100),
  X_1 = rnorm(100),
  X_2 = rnorm(100),
  X_3 = rnorm(100),
  X_4 = rnorm(100),
  X_5 = rnorm(100),
  X_6 = rnorm(100),
  X_7 = rnorm(100)
)
```

Find all 1 through 7 combinations of variables and paste them into a formula with Y as dependent variable:

```r
variables <- colnames(dat)[2:ncol(dat)]
formulas <- list()
for (i in seq_along(variables)) {
  tmp <- combn(variables, i)
  tmp <- apply(tmp, 2, paste, collapse="+")
  tmp <- paste0("Y~", tmp)
  formulas[[i]] <- tmp
}
formulas <- unlist(formulas)
formulas <- sapply(formulas, as.formula)
```

Estimate 127 regression models:

```r
models <- lapply(formulas, lm, data=dat)
```

Comment: thank you so much, it was exactly what I was looking for!! Is there any way to get the value of coefficients of all 127 models? I cannot see them.

Comment: `lapply(models, coef)`